# Export to Excel is not saving to template

Tags: ms-access, vba

Can someone assist me with this code?  It is not exporting the results.  Thank you in advance :)

```
Dim rstName As Recordset
Set rstName = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("qryExportSMI4Charting")

Dim objApp As Object, objMyWorkbook As Object, objMySheet As Object, objMyRange As Object

Set objApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set objMyWorkbook = objApp.Workbooks.Open("M:\BQME Common\BQMO Information Management Team\Utilization Management Data\Utilization Charts\UM Master Charts\MM-UM SMI Eligibility.xlsx")
Set objMySheet = objMyWorkbook.Worksheets("Data")
Set objMyRange = objMySheet.Cells(objApp.ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count + 1, 1)

With objMyRange
 rstName.MoveFirst
 .Clear
 .CopyFromRecordset rstName
    objMySheet.Saveas ("M:\BQME Common\BQMO Information Management Team\Utilization Management Data\Utilization Charts\Q MM-UM SMI Eligibility.xlsx")

End With

Set objMySheet = Nothing
Set objMyWorkbook = Nothing

objApp.Quit
Set objApp = Nothing
```

Answer (score 0):

The code could be inserting the data on a different row than you're expecting.

It looks like you may want to append the data from *qryExportSMI4Charting* to the existing data in the worksheet *Data*. If this is so, try editing line 9 as follows:

**Existing:**

```
Set objMyRange = objMySheet.Cells(objApp.ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count + 1, 1)
```

**Becomes:**

```
Set objMyRange = objMySheet.Cells(objMySheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count + 1, 1)
```

Note that the `UsedRange` that was being returned was from the `ActiveSheet`, not `objMySheet`.